# Printing chunks of words from list using a while loop in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function named printChunks, which takes 3 parameters

```
def printChunks(filename, chunkSize, numChunks)
```

`printChunks` prints a sequence of at most `numChunks` "chunks" created from the words in the text file given by filename.
A chunk is a string formed by concatenating a maximal sequence of words separated by a single space, whose length is no longer than chunkSize. For simplicity, any single word whose length is greater than chunkSize should be treated as a single "oversized" chunk and printed.
So far I have come up with this:

```
wordList = wordListFromFile(filename)
string = ''
i = 0
output = ' '.join(list(string))

for i in range(numChunks):
    while output <= chunkSize:
        for word in wordList:
            string.append(word)
return 'chunk' + str(i) + '(' + str(len(output))
```

please assist i'm new to python

Comment: There's a lot of things that are fundamentally wrong in this code, I think you should probably brush up on variable assignment and loop usage

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  "Please assist" is not a problem description.  It's obvious that you haven't tried to run and debug your code.  We can't even try that for you, because you haven't posted the rest of your code, necessary to support this snippet.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you take an incremental approach.  Write a few lines and get them working; then go on to the next few.  For instance, read in the lines of your file and just print them out.  Next, see whether you can concatenate the entire file into one string.  In this particular code, try printing out all your variables just before the first **for** loop; I think you'll get a few surprises.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, should get you going.

```
long_text = """Bacon ipsum dolor amet ham picanha corned beef shank
swine cow pancetta. Tongue flank jerky pork loin, salami boudin
brisket pastrami venison capicola pig turkey cow chuck. Capicola pork
belly andouille ribeye pancetta kevin pork chop ball tip turducken
doner kielbasa. Shankle pig cow jowl leberkas spare ribs doner
kielbasa shoulder capicola prosciutto corned beef chicken. Corned beef
pig porchetta, kevin tail ham beef ribs ham hock shankle sausage
venison sirloin ball tip.
"""

def get_chunks(text, chunk_size, num_chunks):
    words = text.split(' ')
    chunks = []
    chunk = ''
    for word in words:
        if len(chunk) < chunk_size:
            chunk += word + ' '
        else:
            chunks.append(chunk)
            chunk = ''
        if num_chunks == len(chunks):
            return ' '.join(chunks)

print(get_chunks(long_text, 20, 2))
```

So basically, we take the words and make a list first. Then create an empty list of chunks to fill. Then, we just iterate over the word list, appending to the chunk string until full, then appending to the chunks list and reset chunk.

I get an extra space between chunks, but you can sort that out.